# How to disable URL rewriting after changing backend language

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I changed language in prestashop backend from polish to english, shop's URL started to rewrite from shopname/ to shopname/pl/ - how can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it by disabling the english language. If more than one language is enabled then the language code is added to the URL.